# Build ul li from array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-lists

I got an array that looks like this:

```
var myArray = {
    "ABC.txt": "1",
    "AD.txt": "2",
    "uploads/": "1",
    "uploads/Penguins.jpg": "1",
    "uploads/Tulips.jpg": "2",
    "morefiles.txt": "2"
};
```

I'm trying to make a `ul li` out of it like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="ABC.txt" pos="1">ABC.txt</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="AD.txt" pos="2">AD.txt</a>
  </li>
  <li rel="folder">
    <a href="uploads/" pos="1">uploads</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="uploads/Penguins.jpg" pos="1">Penguins.jpg</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="uploads/Tulips.jpg" pos="2">Tulips.jpg</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="morefiles.txt" pos="2">morefiles.txt</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to make it to `UL LI` using jQuery, and I came up with nothing really just scraps of code nothing even worth putting here.

Please little help.

Comment: You may want to have a look at a template engine. One like Mustache.js or any other one would help you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you need is some kind of templating engine. Check out [**ICanHaz**](http://icanhazjs.com/), where you can have something like:

```
<script id="user" type="text/html">
  <li>
    <p class="name">Hello I'm {{ name }}</p>
    <p><a href="http://twitter.com/{{ twitter }}">@{{ twitter }}</a></p>
  </li>
</script>
```

And the initialization script would be as simple as:

```
var user = ich.user(user_data_object)
```

Also, this article, [Client-Side Templating](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/05/client-side-templating/) will explain you something for:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<ul>
    {{#names}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/names}}
</ul>
```

Along with this:

```
var data = {
    "title": "Story",
    "names": [
        {"name": "Tarzan"},
        {"name": "Jane"}
    ]
}
```

To be converted to this:

```
<h1>Story</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Tarzan</li>
    <li>Jane</ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the variable myArray is not an array, an array is defined inside [ ], so it should look something like this

```
var myArray = [{"ABC.txt" : "1"}, {"AD.txt" : "2"}, {"uploads/" : "1"}, {"uploads/Penguins.jpg" : "1"}, {"uploads/Tulips.jpg" : "2"},{"morefiles.txt" : "2"}];
```

But to generate the html in your question you are probably better off with the following structure:

```
var myArray = [
    {
        "href":"ABC.txt",
        "pos" : "1"
    },{
        "href":"AD.txt",
        "pos":"2"
    },
    ...etc
];
```

Then use another inner array to generate the nested

You can then just iterate through the array using a for loop and append the  elements to the  as you go

Comment: maybe my idea was wrong from the first place, what im doing is taking a ul li, making it to an array by the href (keeping the positions) and synchronizing it with another array (from ul). maybe i should sync them without the arrays straight forward from the ul li, but i cant figure out how to do that without array. (it is for synchronizing a ul li that was saved for the order of the files, and keeping it sync with the current state of files)

Comment: Que?? I think you need to clarify your question, are you creating the javascript array, or is it coming from an external source?